# Communication between custom sibling directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in ctrl.tableData">
  <td><status></status></td>
  <td>{{row.id}}</td>                    
  <td>{{row.firstName}}</td>
  <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>                 
  <td><number-picker></number-picker></td>
</tr>
```

Where 'status 'and 'number-picker' are my custome directives.
I want to change the visibility of 'status' depending on some status of 'number-picker' in the same row. As they are in a grid, there are multiple instances of both directives.
My best solutions so far: 
1. 'ng-repeat' creates a new scope for every 'tr' so I can share a variable between 'status' and 'number-picker' - this method assumes that I have a row variable in $scope, which is bad
2. $broadcast an event from 'number-picker' and catch it with $on on 'status' still using the shared $scope
Is there any cleaner way of achieving this behaviour?
Thanks in advance! 
---EDIT---
Thanks, Vanojx1! 
Your suggestion led me to a solution which I really like. 
I have made some **modifications** to your code so now it is very similar to what I wanted to do.
The point is that now I can use 'numIsEven' to indicate **the change of some inner state** of number-picker **to** any other **sibling directives**.


[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/3C73h2cr3Qk08DCjtwJC?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an attribute like `shared-info`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in ctrl.tableData">
  <td><status shared-info="row.sharedInfo"></status></td>
  <td>{{row.id}}</td>                    
  <td>{{row.firstName}}</td>
  <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>                 
  <td><number-picker shared-info="row.sharedInfo"></number-picker></td>
</tr>
```

then define directives scope using `'='` [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive):

```
.....
    scope: {
        sharedInfo: '='
    },
....
```

row.sharedInfo will be shared between directives

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/aNOsOWbXdiaHFTbOqxa5?p=preview)